# thrust operations empty host array

Tags: cuda, thrust

I want to do some thrust operations but I am not sure how exactly.

Right now , I am receiving am array full of zeros ( the h_a array)

I have :

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>

#include <thrust/device_ptr.h>
#include <thrust/fill.h>
#include <thrust/transform.h>
#include <thrust/functional.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <thrust/generate.h>


template <typename T>
struct square
{
    __host__ __device__
    T operator()( const T& x ) const
    {
        return x * x;
    }

};


int
main(
             int argc,
    const char * argv[] )
{
    const size_t NbOfPoints  = 256;

    int BlocksPerGridX    = 16;
    int BlocksPerGridY    = 16;

    int ThreadsPerBlockX  = 16;
    int ThreadsPerBlockY  = 16;

    // generate random data on the host
    thrust::host_vector<float> h_Kx ( NbOfPoints );
    thrust::generate( h_Kx.begin(), h_Kx.end(), rand );

    thrust::host_vector<float> h_Ky ( NbOfPoints );
    thrust::generate( h_Ky.begin(), h_Ky.end(), rand );

    // transfer to device
    thrust::device_vector<float> dev_Kx = h_Kx;
    thrust::device_vector<float> dev_Ky = h_Ky;

    // create arrays for holding the number of threads per block in each dimension
    int * X , * Y;
    cudaMalloc((void **) &X, ThreadsPerBlockX * BlocksPerGridX * sizeof(*X) );
    cudaMalloc((void **) &Y, ThreadsPerBlockY * BlocksPerGridY * sizeof(*Y) );

    // wrap raw pointer with a device_ptr
    thrust::device_ptr<int> dev_X ( X );
    thrust::device_ptr<int> dev_Y ( Y );

    // use device_ptr in Thrust algorithms
    thrust::fill( dev_X, dev_X + ( ThreadsPerBlockX * BlocksPerGridX ) , (int) 0 );
    thrust::fill( dev_Y, dev_Y + ( ThreadsPerBlockY * BlocksPerGridY ) , (int) 0 );

    // setup arguments
    square<float> square_op;

    // create various vectors
    thrust::device_vector<int> distX ( NbOfPoints );
    thrust::device_vector<int> distY ( NbOfPoints );
    thrust::device_vector<unsigned int> Tmp ( NbOfPoints );
    thrust::host_vector<unsigned int> h_a ( NbOfPoints );
    thrust::device_vector<unsigned int> distXSquared ( NbOfPoints );
    thrust::device_vector<unsigned int> distYSquared ( NbOfPoints );


    // compute distX = dev_Kx - dev_X and distY = dev_Ky - dev_Y
    thrust::transform( dev_Kx.begin(), dev_Kx.begin(), dev_X , distX.begin() , thrust::minus<float>() );
    thrust::transform( dev_Ky.begin(), dev_Ky.begin(), dev_Y , distY.begin() , thrust::minus<float>() );

    //square distances
    thrust::transform( distX.begin(), distX.end(), distXSquared.begin(), square_op );
    thrust::transform( distY.begin(), distY.end(), distYSquared.begin(), square_op );

    // compute Tmp =  distX + distY
    thrust::transform( distXSquared.begin() ,distXSquared.begin() , distYSquared.begin() , Tmp.begin() , thrust::plus<unsigned int>() );
    thrust::copy( Tmp.begin(), Tmp.end(), h_a.begin() );


    for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i ++ )
        printf("\n temp = %u",h_a[ i ] );


return 0;
}
```

UPDATE:

Apart the edits from Robert Crovella , you must edit to integers:

```
square<int> square_op;
thrust::transform( dev_Kx.begin(), dev_Kx.end(), dev_X , distX.begin() , thrust::minus<int>() );
thrust::transform( dev_Ky.begin(), dev_Ky.end(), dev_Y , distY.begin() , thrust::minus<int>() );
```

Comment: And what *exactly* are those "various errors"?

Comment: @Park Young-Bae:I updated..

Comment: How hard would it be to post an example that someone could actually compile and run for themselves? I despair that even after asking *200* questions on [SO], you still haven't seemed to grasp how this place works.

Comment: You're [supposed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ("why isn't this code working?").  That is something that someone else can copy, paste, compile, and run, without adding anything or changing anything, and see the problem.

Comment: @talonmies:Ok, I updated..

Comment: @Robert Crovella:Ok, I updated..

Comment: I'm unable to compile your code as posted.  I assume that means the code you are running is not the code you have posted.  That is not a particularly good way to pose an SO question.  It's better if you actually verify that the code you have posted produces the problem you are describing, as discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Robert Crovella:I removed the gpu error check.It should compile fine now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got several instances of doing zero-length transforms:

```
thrust::transform( dev_Kx.begin(), dev_Kx.begin(), dev_X , distX.begin() , thrust::minus<float>() );
thrust::transform( dev_Ky.begin(), dev_Ky.begin(), dev_Y , distY.begin() , thrust::minus<float>() );
```

and:

```
thrust::transform( distXSquared.begin() ,distXSquared.begin() , distYSquared.begin() , Tmp.begin() , thrust::plus<unsigned int>() );
```

Since the first two parameters to each of the above transforms is the same, the work being done is zero.  Presumably you want the corresponding `.end()` iterators in the second position rather than `.begin()`

When I make those changes, I got non-zero values printed out.  They are quite large, but you appear to be squaring large values, so I'm not sure what your intent is.

Comment: :Hello, I just want to ask.If the "dev_X" above was a vector , I would use "dev_X.begin()".Then , when we use 'begin()' , it means that it will take the whole vector?From the beginning to the end?Thank you!

Comment: you may want to [read up on](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9xd04bzs.aspx) `std::vector`.  `.begin()` is a member function that is part of the `vector` class, that returns an iterator that "points" to the beginning of the vector (i.e. the first element).  It does not imply that the whole vector will be used.  If it's still unclear, I suggest you post a new question.

Comment: :Ok, but in the above line ( the transform ) ,I want to make the substraction 'dev_Kx - dev_X ' .How can I assure that it goes also through all dev_X elements?Because the arguments are  5 in the trasnform function.

Comment: I suggest you post a new question.

Comment: :Ok, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27397775/proper-thrust-call-for-substraction