# proper thrust call for subtraction

Tags: cuda, thrust

Following from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27378260/thrust-operations-empty-host-array/27382436?noredirect=1#comment43241078_27382436).

Assuming that dev_X is a vector.

```
int * X = (int*) malloc( ThreadsPerBlockX * BlocksPerGridX * sizeof(*X) );


for ( int i = 0; i < ThreadsPerBlockX * BlocksPerGridX; i++ )
    X[ i ] = i;

// create device vectors
thrust::device_vector<int> dev_X ( ThreadsPerBlockX * BlocksPerGridX );

//copy to device
thrust::copy( X , X + theThreadsPerBlockX * theBlocksPerGridX , dev_X.begin() );
```

The following is making a subtraction:

```
   thrust::transform( dev_Kx.begin(), dev_Kx.end(), dev_X.begin() , distX.begin() , thrust::minus<float>() );
```

> ```
> dev_Kx - dev_X.
> ```

I want to use the whole `dev_Kx` vector ( as it is used because it goes from .begin to .end() ) and the whole `dev_X` vector.

The above code uses  `dev_X.begin()`.

Is that meaning that it will use the whole `dev_X` vector?  Starting from the beginning?
Or I have to use another extra argument to point to the `dev_X.end()`? ( because in the above function call I can't just use this extra argument )

Also , for example:

If I want to use

```
thrust::transform( dev_Kx, dev_Kx + i , dev_X.begin() ,distX.begin() , thrust::minus<int>() );
```

Then `dev_Kx` would go from 0 to i and the `dev_X.begin()`? It will use the same length? (0 to i?) Or it will use the length of `dev_X`?

Comment: @Park Young-Bae:So , if I want to use   thrust::transform( dev_Kx, dev_Kx + i , dev_X.begin() ,distX.begin() , thrust::minus<int>() ); .The dev_Kx would go from 0 to i and the dev_X.begin() ? It will ue the same length? (0 to i?) Or it will use the length of dev_X?

Comment: @Park Young-Bae:What do you mean by 'the first full range'?Anyway , as I understood , dev_Kx will go from 0 to i and dev_X will go from 0 to ThreadsPerBlockX * BlocksPerGridX , right?PLease make it an answer,thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Many `thrust` (and standard library) functions take a range as a first parameter and then assume all other iterators are backed by containers of the same size. A range is a pair of iterators indicating the *beginning* and *end* of a sequence.

For example:

```
thrust::copy(
    X.begin(),    // begin input iterator
    X.end(),      // end input iterator
    dev_X.begin() // begin output iterator
);
```

This copies the entire contents of `X` into `dev_X`. Why is `dev_X.end()` not needed? Because `thrust` requires that you, the programmer, take the care of properly sizing `dev_X` to be able to contain *at least* as many elements as there are in the input range. If you don't meet that guarantee, then the behavior is undefined.

When you do this:

```
thrust::transform(
    dev_Kx.begin(), // begin input (1) iterator
    dev_Kx.end(),   // end input (1) iterator
    dev_X.begin(),  // begin input (2) iterator
    distX.begin(),  // output iterator
    thrust::minus<float>()
);
```

What `thrust` sees is an input range from `dev_Kx.begin()` to `dev_Kx.end()`. It has an explicit size of `dev_Kx.end() - dev_Kx.begin()`. Why are `dev_X.end()` and `distX.end()` not needed? Because they have an *implicit* size of `dev_Kx.end() - dev_Kx.begin()` too. For example, if there are 10 elements in `dev_Kx`, then `transform` will:

- Use the 10 elements of `dev_Kx`
- Use 10 elements of `dev_X` (which must hold *at least* 10 elements)
- Perform the substraction and store the 10 results in `distX`, which must be able to hold *at least* 10 elements.

Maybe looking at the implementation would clear up any doubts. Here's some pseudo code:

```
void transform(InputIterator input1_begin, InputIterator input1_end,
               InputIterator input2_begin, OutputIterator output,
               BinaryFunction op) {
    while (input1_begin != input1_end) {
        *output++ = op(*input1_begin++, *input2_begin++);
    }
}
```

Notice how only one end iterator is needed.

---

On an unrelated note, the following:

```
int * X = (int*) malloc( ThreadsPerBlockX * BlocksPerGridX * sizeof(*X) );
for ( int i = 0; i < ThreadsPerBlockX * BlocksPerGridX; i++ )
    X[ i ] = i;
```

Could be rewritten in more idiomatic, less error-prone C++ to:

```
std::vector<int> X(ThreadsPerBlockX * BlocksPerGridX);
std::iota(X.begin(), X.end(), 0);
```

Comment: :Ok , I understood.Is there a way though to use for example 10 elements of dev_Kx and more from dev_X?For example , i want to do:  dev_Kx[0] - dev_X[0] , dev_Kx[0] - dev_X[1] , dev_Kx[0] - dev_X[2] ...So , use 10 elements from dev_Kx and for example 100 from dev_X

Comment: That's not doable as-is with `transform`. You would have to implement your own iterator that adapts the 10 elements into 100. Or implement your own transformation algorithm.